# DataSet changes Column name after being matched by schema

Tags: c#, dataset

Let's say I've created a DataTable object that created a column with a name of "5_min". I usually extract the Schema to create instance of the same DataSet for succeeding instances.

The schema re-writes the Column name of `5_min` to `_x0035__min`. I'm wondering how do i prevent this from ever happening?

```
DataTable newDT = new DataTable("SomeDataTable");
DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[1];

DataColumn dcID = new DataColumn("ID");
dcID.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Guid");
newDT.Columns.Add(dcID);
keys[0] = dcID;
newDT.PrimaryKey = keys;

var dataTypes = DA.GetSysVars(GlobalSysVar.DataTypes);
DataColumn dcColumn = new DataColumn("5_min");
dcColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
dcColumn.AllowDBNull = true;
newDT.Columns.Add(dcColumn);

DataSet ds = new DataSet("Custom");
ds.Tables.Add(newDT);


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema id="Custom" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="Custom" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="SomeDataTable">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID" msdata:DataType="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="_x0035__min" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="Constraint1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//SomeDataTable" />
      <xs:field xpath="ID" />
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Is this some kind of reference problem where changes in one reflects in other?